# hdmi not showing up in xrandr

Tags: xorg, hdmi, xrandr

Everything used to work until recently. Now, whenever I connect my HDMI monitor to my laptop nothing happens. Running xrandr doesn't show the HDMI output. Can anyone help out? I've been trying to fix this for the last 3 hours. I even reinstalled unity but that didn't work.

I'm on 14.04 ubuntu.

Any help is appreciated!!

Vladimir

```
> xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
344mm x 193mm 
    1920x1080      60.1 +   59.9     40.0     
    1680x1050      60.0     59.9      
    1600x1024      60.2      
    1400x1050      60.0      
    1280x1024      60.0      
    1440x900       59.9      
    1280x960       60.0      
    1360x768       59.8*    60.0      
    1152x864       60.0      
    1024x768       60.0      
    800x600        60.3     56.2      
    640x480        59.9   
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Graphics card:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

Comment: what graphics card and what graphics driver are you using ?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a sleepless night of googling and trying things out (like reinstalling unity and the x drivers), I decided to try out Intel's approach. Apparently they officially support linux and they have a graphics driver installer (link below). After downloading and installing everything started working again.

I'm in Ubuntu heaven again.

Enjoy!

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7

Comment: A sleepless night of 1.5 hours???  :P  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby, I posted the question after I exhausted all of my options :)

Comment: Goog one (and upvoted - twice)

Comment: Seems like link is not available anymore :(

Comment: @М.Б. Clicked the link, says I'm not authorised to access the page. But I found this: https://01.org/temp-linuxgraphics/downloads/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7

Comment: Hey @Pixel thanks a lot! This is looking promising! Since now, everything is working good so far and i don't want to experiment. But going to bookmark this.

Comment: @М.Б. how did you get it to work? I'm still having problems :-( I'm running Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: @Pixel hey, sorry for the delay... I'm trying to remind myself what exactly did the trick, but can't remind, since I've tried a ton of things. I've struggled so hard with this by spending around 36h (with just few hours of sleep) to solve this. I can remember that I've completely removed any nvidia drivers and installed the latest version. The version: 435.21. I can remind that i've instaled `CUDA` too (check this: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html). Also, try to install intel graphics before, mentioned above. Let me know how's going.