# XFCE dual monitors stopped working

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce

I have a Xubuntu machine using two displays which worked fine, now they aren't recognized by the system. They are plugged to the machine and powered. This is the xrandr output:

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9
   1600x1024      60.2
   1400x1050      60.0
   1280x1024      60.0
   1440x900       59.9
   1280x960       60.0
   1360x768       59.8     60.0
   1152x864       60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

This is on linux...win10 recognizes them just fine.

Comment: Did you tried to connect to same machine but with another  monitor/cables to discard hardware issues?, you may also want to try the same monitor/cables into another machine.

Comment: Yes, did that to no avail.

Comment: I only found [Intel's drives related solutions](https://askubuntu.com/a/593490/260379) and others with [xorg.conf and nvidia/nouveau drivers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25769). 
Did you by any chance updated your video drivers?

Comment: @Leprosy, did you ever resolve this?